# What is the minimum video resolution I need to identify anyone with facial recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, python, facial-recognition, opencv

I am currently working on a small project where I am trying to automate some stuff at home. I am building a model capable of identifying my face with OpenCV. This will be a live feed.

I am making the project's estimations and have a really low budget. Therefore I am trying to identify what could be the minimum quality video feed I can pass to my algorithm to identify any face. For now I am just trying to identify mine.

I understand facial recognition works primarily on the unique pattern that could be found in the face. What is the minimum video resolution I need to identify anyone with facial recognition?

Comment: You lost me on mentioning a budget and 'video fee'.  OpenCV is free.  Cameras with plenty of resolution don't cost much.  Why are you concerned about minimizing resolution?  What is the resolution of your live feed? How far away will your face be from the camera?

Comment: well actually budget is very low, but I can purchase a small camera no more than $50, I already some prospects, the max distance is about 50 cm, mim distance 20 cm, I'm concerned to see if I could use the cheapest camera I could get or if a raspberry camera will do the trick, that's why.

Comment: What is the resolution of your Raspberry camera?

Comment: I don't have a raspberry camera right now, I just got the raspberry 2, but I did some digging and 720p will be good enough, nevertheless, I'd like to know like what could be the minimum resolution a face could be identified by a face recognition algorithm

Answer (score 3):

On page 2 of Axis' web page [Identification and Recognition](https://www.axis.com/learning/web-articles/identification-and-recognition/index) there is an estimate of the minimum number of pixels needed for identification, recognition and detection.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty standard minimum "quality" (better said resolution in pixels between the eyes) needed for a facial recognition system:

> [Ensure that the image contains a frontal view of the face, good
> lighting](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iva/2.0.0?topic=recognition-minimum-requirements-face), and **at least 80 pixels between the eyes**.
>
> [the bare minimum to identify a human face](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/facial-recognition) would be 25 to 75 pixels
> just between the eyes

In the end it comes to a detailed study of the camara location, distance, light, etc...